# Iteratively testing the performance of portfolio weights in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration, portfolio

I have a portfolio of **x** (let's say x = 8) stock factors with weights **w**. I can test the performance of these factors in an **equally weighted** manner by using function **F(w) = p**, where the output **p** is a performance metric. The df of portfolio weights for the first test looks like this:

```
    weight
0   12.57
1   12.49
2   12.49
3   12.49
4   12.49
5   12.49
6   12.49
7   12.49
```

Where I used 100/8 rounded down to two decimals and gave the first factor the remainder on top of that as below:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns = ['weight'], data = [(100/factorsdf.shape[0] // 0.01 / 100)]*factorsdf.shape[0])
weights['weight'].iloc[0] = weights['weight'].iloc[0] + round(100 - (100/factorsdf.shape[0] // 0.01 / 100) * factorsdf.shape[0],2)
```

What I now want to do is **iteratively improve** upon these weights. The way I think of doing this is by incrementally subtracting half of the weight (here: 12.49/2 = 6.245) of the bottom weight (with index 7) and adding it to the weight above (index 6).

```
incremental_weight = (100/factorsdf.shape[0] // 0.01 / 100)/2
```

Hence, in the **first iteration** I would test the equally weighted portfolio.

In the **next iteration** I would test:

```
    weight
0   12.57
1   12.49
2   12.49
3   12.49
4   12.49
5   12.49
6   18.735
7   6.245
```

In case this does not improve metric **p**, I will try adding it to the next weight element in the dataframe like so:

```
    weight
0   12.57
1   12.49
2   12.49
3   12.49
4   12.49
5   18.735
6   12.49
7   6.245
```

In case it does improve, I will subtract another 6.245 of the bottom element and try adding it to the one above. If that doesn't improve **p**, I will try adding it to the one above that, and so on, until I've tried adding it to all the other elements.

After that I will do the same procedure for the element above the bottom element (with index 6), subtracing 6.245 and iteratively adding it to the other elements. And so on. Until metric **p** can no longer be improved upon.

What would be a good way to program this in pandas in a relatively efficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work if I have understood fully (I have added comments in the code):

```
import pandas as pd; import numpy as np
# my random generated factor scores
factorsdf = pd.DataFrame({"Factor": np.random.randint(0, 100, 8)})
# weights evenly allocated (from your code)
weights = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['weight'], data = [(100/factorsdf.shape[0] // 0.01 / 100)]*factorsdf.shape[0])
weights['weight'].iloc[0] = weights['weight'].iloc[0] + round(100 - (100/factorsdf.shape[0] // 0.01 / 100) * factorsdf.shape[0],2)

# weight to increment by (from your code)
incremental_weight = (100/factorsdf.shape[0] // 0.01 / 100)/2

# the F(w) function: weights must be first, from np.apply_along_axis below
def F_w(weights, factorsdf):
    # here it is just the dot product of the random factors and the weights.
    p = np.dot(factorsdf, weights.T/100)
    return p

# initial value of p
p = F_w(np.array(weights["weight"]), np.array(factorsdf["Factor"]))

print("p: ", p)

# rows above the weight that is being decreased
i = len(weights) - 1

# copy of weights to change
weights_c = weights.copy(deep=True)

# can't decrease the top weight, because none above to change
while i >= 1:
    print("i: ", i)
    
    # series with 0s everywhere except on row that will be decreasing the weight
    dec = pd.Series([0]*(len(weights_c)-1) + [incremental_weight]).shift(-len(weights)+1+i).fillna(0)
    # increment array has all possible options for increasing weights above
    inc = np.identity(i)*incremental_weight
    # row that is decreasing should not increase
    inc = np.vstack([inc, [0]*inc.shape[1]])
    # if other rows below have a weight (are not 0) then these won't increase either
    while inc.shape[0] < len(weights_c):
        inc = np.vstack([inc, [0]*inc.shape[1]])
    # if weight will be below 0 then should move up, also if there is only one row left
    if ((weights_c["weight"].sub(dec)<0).sum() > 0) or (inc.shape[0] == 1):
        i -= 1
        continue
    # subtract the increment from the weight
    weights_c["weight"] = weights_c["weight"].sub(dec)
    
    # array of possible weightings when incrementing rows above
    weights_arr = np.repeat(np.array(weights_c), inc.shape[1], axis=1) + inc
    
    print("weights_arr: ", weights_arr)
    print("weights_c: ", weights_c)
    print("factorsdf: ", np.array(factorsdf).T[:, :weights_arr.shape[0]])
    
    # return the p values for F(w) for all the possible variations
    res = np.apply_along_axis(F_w, 0, weights_arr, np.array(factorsdf).T[:, :weights_arr.shape[0]])
    # if any of these are greater than current p...
    if res.max() > p:
        # set new value of p
        p = res.max()
        # find which row the increment should be added to
        x = res.argmax()
    
        # add the increment to the correct row
        weights_c["weight"].iloc[x] += incremental_weight
        
        print("x: ", x)
    # if not, move on
    else:
        weights_c["weight"] = weights_c["weight"].add(dec)
        i -= 1
    
    # if the bottom weight is 0, remove this row from calculations
    if weights_c["weight"].iloc[-1] == 0:
        weights_c = weights_c.iloc[:-1]
        i -= 1
    
    print("weights_c: ", weights_c)

# print final weightings and max value of p
print("weights_c: ", weights_c)
print("p: ", p)
```

It can definitely be cleaned up a bit, with some of the while loops removed, but this might give you a good starting point.

As you can see, I have made use of numpy a lot more than pandas, and there would be less code if the weights and factors were arrays to start.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up with a nested for loop but your answer will most likely (partly) replace the code I wrote myself :)